# cdo: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Core.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, shared-library, merge

I am trying to use [Climate Data Operators (CDO)](https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/) to merge several [NetCDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetCDF) files into one. I installed it successfully, although when I try to merge the file with:

```
cdo mergetime *.nc output.nc
```

I come across this error:

```
cdo: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Core.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Did I not install CDO correctly? Or is it problem with Ubuntu?

I am using Windows Subsystem for Linux, as you can see in this image:

[image: image showing WSL terminal]

I already used this solution: https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/Fix-error-while-loading-shared-libraries:-libQt5Core.so.5

There they used this command:

```
sudo strip --remove-section=.note.ABI-tag /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5
```

But you notice in the screenshot that it didn't show any such directory. It could be that I am failing to find the proper directory because I am using Ubuntu on Windows, and Ubuntu's file is hidden somewhere I don't possibly have any idea of.

Either way, I'll be really grateful if I get any help regarding this problem.

Comment: Don't confuse library names with package names - the name of the package that provides the `libQt5Core.so.5` library is `libqt5core5a`. In x86_64 Ubuntu (whether WSL or otherwise), it will install in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` rather than `/usr/lib64`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you [@steeldriver for pointing to the solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245160/cdo-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libqt5core-so-5-cannot-open-shared-o/1451585#comment2099402_1245160). I was confusing **library names with package names**. I used:

```
sudo strip --remove-section=.note.ABI-tag /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
```

and was able to successfully run CDO.